# Simiplified explanation of mlabel command

Tags: command-line, disk-management

Can someone explanation to me the command:

```
sudo mlabel -i /dev/sdb1 ::my_external
```

I understand what the command does but what I do not understand

`-i` - it is not listed in the man as a option?

`::` - it must be used to id a disk?

How does the `sudo` command use `mlabel` to add a label?

Another question: can I use the same command to label my primary disk running UBuntu or must I unmount the disk first? (I know Gparted needs unmount disk.)

(I use this command to label USB drives with FAT32.)

Comment: The full documentation reveals all: https://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/manual/mtools.html#drive-letters If you like I can turn this into a formal answer but you have asked multiple questions.....

Answer (score 1):

From [`man mtools`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/mtools.1.html), section `Common features of all mtools commands`:

```
The drive letter : (colon) has a special meaning. It is used to  access
image  files which are directly specified on the command line using the
-i options.

   mcopy -i my-image-file.bin ::file1 ::file2 .

This copies file1 and file2 from the image file (my-image-file.bin)  to
the /tmp directory.
```

So, this `mlabel` command is applying the label `my_external` to the drive `:`, which is specified using the `-i /dev/sdb1` option.

The pre-installed Disks program can change labels without unmounting disks, so it might be possible for `mlabel` to do so.